# JButton KeyBinding and setActionCommand

Tags: java, swing, key, key-bindings

I'm fairly new to Swing and am having trouble understand a KeyBinding concept.
I'm trying to add a `JButton` to my `JPanel` and then setting its action command and KeyBinding. Here's my code:

```
JButton b = new JButton("1");
MyAction myaction = new MyAction("1");
b.setAction(myaction);
b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "one");
b.getActionMap().put("one", myaction);
b.setActionCommand("one");
```

`MyAction` here, is an inner class

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    public MyAction(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Action command is: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Now if I press the button, I get this output:

```
Action command is: one
```

However, if I press '1' on the keyboard, I get this:

```
Action command is: 1
```

Why is that so? And what should I do to get the same action command irrespective of whether the action is fired by button press or a keybinding?

Comment: You're binding it to the 0 key not the 1 key.

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted the code wrong here. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider setting the Action command key in the AbstractAction itself:

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    public MyAction(String text) {
        super(text);
        putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "one"),
    }
    //...
```

for example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] NUMBER_TEXTS = {
      "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
   };


   public Foo2() {

      for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         String numberString = String.valueOf(i + 1);
         Action numberBtnAction = new NumberBtnAction(numberString, NUMBER_TEXTS[i]);
         JButton btn = new JButton(numberBtnAction);
         InputMap inMap = btn.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
         ActionMap actionMap = btn.getActionMap();

         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(numberString.charAt(0));
         inMap.put(keyStroke, NUMBER_TEXTS[i]);
         actionMap.put(NUMBER_TEXTS[i], numberBtnAction);

         add(btn);
      }

   }

   private class NumberBtnAction extends AbstractAction {
      public NumberBtnAction(String numberString, String numberText) {
         super(numberString);
         putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, numberText);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
Or alternatively, you could have a separate key binding action that simply presses the button:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] NUMBER_TEXTS = {
      "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
   };


   public Foo2() {

      for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         String numberString = String.valueOf(i + 1);
         Action numberBtnAction = new NumberBtnAction(numberString, NUMBER_TEXTS[i]);
         JButton btn = new JButton(numberBtnAction);
         Action pressBtnAction = new PressButtonAction(btn);
         InputMap inMap = btn.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
         ActionMap actionMap = btn.getActionMap();

         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(numberString.charAt(0));
         inMap.put(keyStroke, NUMBER_TEXTS[i]);
         //!! actionMap.put(NUMBER_TEXTS[i], numberBtnAction);
         actionMap.put(NUMBER_TEXTS[i], pressBtnAction);

         add(btn);
      }

   }

   private class NumberBtnAction extends AbstractAction {
      public NumberBtnAction(String numberString, String numberText) {
         super(numberString);
         putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, numberText);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
      }
   }

   private class PressButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      private AbstractButton btn;

      public PressButtonAction(AbstractButton btn) {
         this.btn = btn;
      }


      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         btn.doClick();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: By using `putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, numberText);` aren't different `Action`s still being triggered on button press and key press? `btn.doClick()` is a work-around but is there no way I can have the same Actions for both at the time of creation of the JButton?

Comment: @Siddharth: no the same Action is being triggered in my first code example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in what is been activated.  When you press the button, the button is been activated and therefore it's `actionCommand` is been seeded as part of the `ActionEvent`

When you press the <kbd>1</kbd> key, the `Action`, associated with the key binding is been activated and it is using the text you supplied as the `actionCommand`.

If you want to use the same action for both, then seed the `Action` to both the key binding and the button...

```
MyAction myaction = new MyAction("1");
JButton b = new JButton(myaction);
b.setAction(myaction);
b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "one");
b.getActionMap().put("one", myaction);
```

This way, when the button is activated or the kbd>1 key is pressed, it will use the same `Action`...this is kind of the point of `Action`s

**Updated**

> for some reason, it still doesn't solve it. I am getting same outputs

Well, I'm not sure what you're doing, but it works fine for me...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestAction();
    }

    public TestAction() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton b = new JButton("1");
            MyAction myaction = new MyAction("1");
            b.setAction(myaction);
            b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "one");
            b.getActionMap().put("one", myaction);
            //b.setActionCommand("one");
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            });

            add(b);
        }

    }

    class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MyAction(String text) {
            super(text);
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "one");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Action command is: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

}
```

**Updated**

Based on the linked example in the comments, you add `putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "one");` to `MyAction` class, it will print `one` regardless of how the action is triggered.

In fact, I'd get rid of the `setActionCommand` call on the button altogether.

In fact, when using `Action`s, I don't even bother with the action commands, as the `Action` is self contained, which kind of the point...

Comment: You're correct about different actions being activated but, for some reason, it still doesn't solve it. I am getting same outputs.

Comment: The only reason you will get two different results (after applying `Action`) is probably because you still have an `ActionListener` attached to the `JButton`, you don't need it...

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, it still doesn't work for me. I don't understand what problem it could be. There aren't any `ActionListener` attached either. Just to be sure, I wrote this again - http://pastebin.com/DCZtvKzX

Comment: What do you by "doesn't work"?  It it does is prints "one"...?  If I change the `actionCommand` property to `1` it displays `1`...?

Comment: It prints `1` on keypress even if the `actionCommand` is set to "one". I expect it to print "one" instead.

Comment: Here's the thing, remove the `setActionCommand` from the `JButton` and use `putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "one");` to specify the action command, frankly, when using `Action`, I don't even both with it, as the action is self contained